# Text box stops updating after a condition occurs

Tags: c#, textbox

In this program, whenever any of the statements under else occur, it doesn't go back to state 0 and perform the actions in that state, which is what I'm trying to do. Instead, the txtStatus, and txtScore boxes just continue to display "Roll again!" which is what is displayed when jumping to state 2.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
   int die1 = 0;
    int die2 = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int state = 0;
    int point = 0;
    //int point2;
    int score = 0;

    //private int score;
    //private int state;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        picDie1L.Visible = false;
        picDie1R.Visible = false;
        picDie2L.Visible = false;
        picDie2R.Visible = false;
        picDie3L.Visible = false;
        picDie3R.Visible = false;
        picDie4L.Visible = false;
        picDie4R.Visible = false;
        picDie5L.Visible = false;
        picDie5R.Visible = false;
        picDie6L.Visible = false;
        picDie6R.Visible = false;


        Random rand = new Random();
        die1 = rand.Next(1, 7);
        die2 = rand.Next(1, 7);
        total = (die1 + die2);

        txtDie1.Text = die1.ToString();
        txtDie2.Text = die2.ToString();
        txtTotal.Text = total.ToString();

        {
            if (die1 == 1)
            {
                picDie1L.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die1 == 2)
            {
                picDie2L.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die1 == 3)
            {
                picDie3L.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die1 == 4)
            {
                picDie4L.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die1 == 5)
            {
                picDie5L.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die1 == 6)
            {
                picDie6L.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die2 == 1)
            {
                picDie1R.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die2 == 2)
            {
                picDie2R.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die2 == 3)
            {
                picDie3R.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die2 == 4)
            {
                picDie4R.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die2 == 5)
            {
                picDie5R.Visible = true;
            }
            if (die2 == 6)
            {
                picDie6R.Visible = true;
            }               
        if (state == 0)
            {
                picPuck4.Visible = false;
                picPuck5.Visible = false;
                picPuck6.Visible = false;
                picPuck8.Visible = false;
                picPuck9.Visible = false;
                picPuck10.Visible = false;
                txtStatus.Text = string.Empty;
                state = 1;
                txtPoint.Text = string.Empty;

            }
        }
        if (state == 1)


        {
            if (total == 7 || total == 11)
            {
                txtStatus.Text = "You are a winner!";
                score++;
                txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
                state = 0;

            }
            if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12)
            {
                txtStatus.Text = "You lose. Play again!";
                score--;
                txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
                state = 0;

            }
            if (total == 4 || total == 5 || total == 6 || total == 8 || total == 9 || total == 10 || total == 12)
            {


                txtStatus.Text = "Roll again!";
                point = int.Parse(txtTotal.Text);
                txtPoint.Text = point.ToString();
                state = 2;

                if (total == 4)
                    picPuck4.Visible = true;
                if (total == 5)
                    picPuck5.Visible = true;
                if (total == 6)
                    picPuck6.Visible = true;
                if (total == 8)
                    picPuck8.Visible = true;
                if (total == 9)
                    picPuck9.Visible = true;
                if (total == 10)
                    picPuck10.Visible = true;



            }
        }
        else        
        {
            if (point == total)
            {
                txtStatus.Text = "You are a winner!";
                score++;
                txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
                state = 0;
            }
            if (total == 7)
            {
                txtStatus.Text = "You lose. Play again!";
                score--;
                txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
                state = 0;
            }
            if (total != 7 || point != total)
            {
                txtStatus.Text = "Roll again!";
                state = 2;
            }
        }




    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please make the code more readable (i.e. I see 2 closed curly brackets ( '}' ) in first if statement but only one is opened, and also write down the flow of the code (what's the initial value of the `score` and what happens once the code finishes executing the `else` statement).

Comment: @miselking i edited it to include everything i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change the last `else` statement to this:

```
if (point == total)
{
    txtStatus.Text = "You are a winner!";
    score++;
    txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
    state = 0;
}
else if (total == 7)
{
    txtStatus.Text = "You lose. Play again!";
    score--;
    txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
    state = 0;
}
else
{
    txtStatus.Text = "Roll again!";
    state = 2;
}
```

**Explanation**: When `total` has any value but 7 you switch *state* to 2. Because of that, when you roll again you immediately go the last `else` statement and execute those 3 `if` statements inside it. In this scenario, the last `if` statement is always true (since `total` is never 7 in this scenario) therefore the text remains "Roll again" and state is never changed (remains 2).

This will fix your issue, but I think you need to change the logic (for example, `point` is always equal to `total`, since `point == txtTotal.text == total` which may not be desired behavior).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much!! also thank you for explaining it as well, super helpful

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is here

```
if (total != 7 || point != total)
{
    txtStatus.Text = "Roll again!";
    state = 2;
}
```

as you see the condition is most of the time true! the only time that this is false is when **`total == point == 7`**